# menuBar.addAction change the text

Tags: python, pyqt4, qmenubar

I'm using python QtGui.

When I want to change the text, I got error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main2.py", line 140, in ChangeLanguage
self.fileMenu2.setText("www")
AttributeError: 'QMenu' object has no attribute 'setText'
```

Here is my Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui,QMainWindow
...
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
    menubar = self.menuBar()
    self.fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('test')
...
    def ChangeLanguage(self):
    self.fileMenu.setText("test2")
```

How should I change the text ?

THanks

edit: Sorry , It's QtGui.QMainWindow ... not Tkinter

Comment: That doesn't look like tkinter code. `QMenu` Looks like a qt widget.

Comment: Oh, I'm wrong.  Sorry,I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QMenu` class doesn't have a `setText` method like `QAction` does. You need to use `setTitle` instead:

```
    self.fileMenu.setTitle("test2")
```

Comment: It changed!  Thanks you!